# CAKeyframeAnimation opacity behaves strangely with UIImageView sublayers

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

I'm attempting to animate the opacity of a UIView when it a UIScrollView is scrolled. To those ends I'm setting up a keyframe animation (with the following code) and changing its timeOffset value as the scrollView scrolls.

```
    let alphaAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    alphaAnimation.duration = 1.0
    alphaAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    alphaAnimation.autoreverses = false
    alphaAnimation.values = [1.0, 0.0]
    alphaAnimation.keyTimes = [0.0, 1.0]
    alphaAnimation.repeatCount = 0
    alphaAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

    headerInfoView.layer.add(alphaAnimation, forKey: "animate opacity")
    headerInfoView.layer.speed = 0.0
    headerInfoView.layer.timeOffset = CFTimeInterval(0.0)
    headerInfoView.layer.opacity = 1.0
```

That's getting set up in `viewWillAppear`.

This actually works well *except that* I have an imageView child in headerInfoView and for some reason when timeOffset < ~0.1, the alpha of the imageView is approximately 0. If I comment out the above code, the alpha of the imageView stays the same.

I've tried waiting until the imageView.image fetch callback to attach the above CAKeyframeAnimation and that also does not work.

Any thoughts on why these imageView sublayers seem to disappear on `viewWillAppear`?